# How to drag object without elasticity with joint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

see my gif, I drag ragdoll, with move cube object, I have disable "Spring" in hinge joint, but the ragdoll still perform like spring, so how to drag object like not elastic rope?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Increase Connected Mass Scale on your joint.

Here's relevant documentation, but in your case the one you want to raise is the connected mass.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint-massScale.html

> The scale to apply to the inverse mass and inertia tensor of the body
>   prior to solving the constraints.
>
> Scale mass and the inertia tensor to make the joints solver converge
>   faster, thus resulting in less stretch of the limbs of a typical
>   ragdoll. Most useful in conjunction with Joint.connectedMassScale.